# Solving a for the vertex of a sine graph, possibly using derivatives

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have been trying to emulate the path of a cannon ball, and I have come up with a parametric equation to do so. In this case:

p = power (which is a control variable)

a = headwind or tailwind (headwind is positive, and this is in m/s)

g = gravity (9.8 m/s)

f = firing angle (in degrees, from 0 to 90)

The equation is:

x(t) = $-\frac{a}{2}t^2+p\cos \left(f\right)t$

y(t) = $-\frac{g}{2}t^2+p\sin \left(f\right)t$

I used these, and the quadratic formula, to make a function for how far the cannonball travels for any given f, where f is the independent variable - this is not a parametric equation:

$l(x)=-\frac{2ap^2\sin \left(f\right)^2}{g^2}+\frac{p^2\sin \left(2f\right)}{g}$

Where l = the length of the flight and f = the firing angle. However, I noticed that as I change *a* and *g*, the optimal flight distance, or the vertex of this function, changes. I wanted to create a function of *a*, where the optimal *f* is the output. In this case, g can be assumed to be a constant. I tried to do this be finding the derivative of l(x) - and simplification to output *f*. Also, I divided both sides by $p^2$ which doesn't change the optimal flight. Therefore, the simplified derivative is:

$l'(x) = -a\sin(2x)+2g\cos(2x)$

This derivative's root between 0 and 90 is the vertex of l(x), but I have no idea how to calculate the root of the function. Additionally, I did verification and both l(x) and l'(x) are the correct formulas.

So, in essence, my problem is specifically how to calculate the root of l'(x) between 0 and 90, but finding the vertex of l(x) is equally helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Ok... I got it. I set the new equation $a\sin(2x) = 2g\cos(2x)$, and divided both sides of the equation by $2g\cos(2x)$ Trig identities make that $\frac{a}{2g}\tan(2x) = 1$. Then, I rewrote it: $\tan(2x) = \frac{2g}{a}$. Here, I used the inverse tangent properties to make: $2x = \arctan(\frac{2g}{a})$. Then I divided the whole thing by two, to get the equation: $x = \frac{\arctan(\frac{2g}{a})}{2}$. So, x is the optimal firing angle, and now the dependent variable, and *a* is what I want as the independent variable. Therefore, my final equation, rewriting for graphing terms, to show off the change in firing angle from the change in wind is:

$f(x) = \frac{\arctan(\frac{2g}{x})}{2}$